# Ubuntu Drivers - No Internet

Tags: drivers, server, system-installation, ethernet, hardware

Trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04.01 - the Ethernet driver is not detected.

The motherboard does not have onboard Wi-Fi.

I have a USB Wi-Fi dongle available but not sure how to mount etc. and if its possible to use.

Is there a way to get this machine going, either via the Wi-Fi dongle or potentially installing the onboard Ethernet driver via a USB drive after downloading from another machine? (Realtek RTL8125)